# No bash in /usr/bin

Tags: bash, solaris

Я новичок в `Oracle 10`, пытаюсь его выучить. Поэтому простите за глупый вопрос. Я пытаюсь переключится на bash в `OracleSolaris 10` Комманда `which bash` показывает `no bash is /usr/sbin /usr/bin` Как:

```
no bash is /usr/sbin /usr/bin
```

Как я могу переключится на bash Заранее спасибо за помощь?

Comment: у нас Русский СО, переведите на русский, пожалуйста

Comment: А что значит "подключиться на `bash`" ? Под Оракл 10 подразумевается база?

Comment: Простите я плохо говорю по русски. Я пытаюсь переключится с shell на bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

судя по всему, имеется в виду [операционная система *solaris*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris), а не [база данных *oracle*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database).

[установить пакет](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E29492/ewbej.html) в этой операционной системе можно так:

```
$ pkgadd -a имя-пакета
```

---

скорее всего, программа *bash* присутствует в одноимённом пакете.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

по умолчанию bash в системе solaris находится в другом месте:

```
/usr/bin/bash
```

попробуй поискать:

```
find / -name bash
```

для того, чтобы не менять путь в готовых скриптах лучше сделать симлинк:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/bash /bin/bash
```